# Pandas: How do I make a dataframe manually calculate missing values by averaging adjacent values?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, nan, dataframe

I have a (200 column x 5000 row) data-frame and occasionally it has a missing value. 
I would like it to fill in the missing values by averaging the cell to the right
and the cell to the left.

For example:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
1  34  54  56   0  78
2  12  87  78  23  12 
3  78  35   0  72  31
4  84  25  14  56   0
5  26  82  13  14  34
```

In this dataframe there are three missing values:

```
1) D1
2) C3
3) E4

D1 should be (78 + 56)/2 = 67
C3 should be (72 + 32)/2 = 55
E4 should be (26 + 56)/2 = 41
```

So the resulting data-frame should be:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
1  34  54  56  67  78
2  12  87  78  23  12 
3  78  35  55  72  31
4  84  25  14  56  41
5  26  82  13  14  34
```

Is there a natural way to do this in pandas?

Comment: see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html

Comment: Why E4 = (26 + 56)/2, does this means that the cell right to E4 is A5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think new [interpolate()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html#interpolation) method could do this, I've tried to do this by hand like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[34,12,78,84,26], "B":[54,87,35,25,82], "C":[56,78,0,14,13], "D":[0,23,72,56,14], "E":[78,12,31,0,34]})

# get flat array from DataFrame
a = np.array(df).flatten()

# get flat array, zeroes replaced with left + right / 2
res = np.where(a == 0, (np.roll(a, 1) + np.roll(a, -1)) / 2, a) 

# convert back to DataFrame
df_new = pd.DataFrame(res.reshape(df.shape), columns = df.columns)

#     A   B   C   D   E
# 0  34  54  56  67  78
# 1  12  87  78  23  12
# 2  78  35  53  72  31
# 3  84  25  14  56  41
# 4  26  82  13  14  34
```